# why can't i get HTML by using Python of some website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Why can't I get HTML by using Python of some website?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scrape_url = 'https://dict.naver.com/linedict/zhendict/?q=%E9%99%8D&st=100&r_lt=000&q_enc=UTF-8&r_format=json&e_enc=UTF-8#/cnen/entry/f7d019715a9149fe909e56b52dd072ad'

headers = {"User-Agent": ""}

web_response = requests.get(scrape_url, headers=headers)

if web_response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_response.text, 'html.parser')  
    print(soup)
```

the problem is HTML that  get in Python  is not the same as HTML show on the sites  [HTML from Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b16V.png)        [HTML from site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XApbZ.png)

Comment: Can you explain what is happening when you attempt to scrape with the Naver website? Your code worked for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i want to get the meaning of chinese words  but  the problem is HTML that get in Python is not the same as HTML show on the sites  even though i use the same url

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, and I'm able to get the HTML of the site.

If you're unable to get the HTML of some sites it could be because, Some sites  implement methods against robots such as captcha, checking for a proper header, or blocking IPs that send too many requests.
using websites such as myhttpheader will give you headers that you can use to bypass blocks on most sites.

Comment: acuully i can get the HTML  but the problem is HTML that get in Python is not the same as HTML show on the sites even though  i use the same url

Comment: do right click and view source, on the webpage, that is the webpage HTML before any scripts have been ran. Beautiful Soup can only view this HTML